# Hybris Live Chat Extension/Addon

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I need to implement a live text chat with support team in Hybris, however I don't see any extension related to this in Commerce 2105 Suite, is there any extension that can achieve this or do I need to integrate with third party libraries? In that case, which one should I use? Is there any open-source free chat library?

Comment: Hey, There is no OOTB extension or addon for this (as far as I know). I think you need to implement it completely by your own.